# position all buttons the same horizontally

Tags: css, button, plsql, alignment

I am printing out set of buttons from plsql with the button definition in CSS.

```
print_out('"<button class=\"btn\" OnClick=\"displaySection(''TOC'',''' || to_char(i) || ''')\">' ||     
    g_sections(i).name || '" +');
```

I am printing this out inside a table row.

The problem I am running into is the length of the text is making the button go up or down based on other buttons. The longer the text is in the button then the button goes higher than other buttons. I also noticed once I had my icon image at the end of the text then the button moves down 1 pixel.

Here is my button CSS

```
.btn {
  border: #000000;
  border-style: solid; 
  border-width: 2px;
  width:190;
  height:50;
  border-radius: 6px;   
  background: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #B0B0B0);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: blue; 
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
```

I do not want to set the absolute positioning of the buttons in the page as number of buttons can be different in each case. So float based on how wide is the browser window.

So question is how to make sure the buttons are always aligned horizontally perfectly with each other.

Thanks

Comment: Is this question related to Oracle Apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "vertical-align: middle;" to the button class and that worked